# JQuery - set value attribute of 1st <option> in <select> tag

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to dynamically set the value attribute of the first  in a  tag named listSelector. The below isn't working, any ideas?

Please note I'm using JQuery 1.7.2.

I don't think it's anything to do with the JSON call as applying response.posts[0].url to a a href is fine. Cheers.

```
    $.getJSON('http://onrepeatthisweek.tumblr.com/api/read/json?callback=?',
       function(response) {
           $("#listSelector option").first().attr('value',response.posts[0].url);
       });

    <select id="listSelector" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
       <option>Latest</option>
       <option value="2014top20">2014 Top 20</option>
       <option value="2013top20">2013 Top 20</option>
       <option value="2012top20">2012 Top 20</option>
       <option value="2011top20">2011 Top 20</option>
       <option value="2010top20">2010 Top 20</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.val()` here instead:

```
 $("#listSelector option").first().val(response.posts[0].url);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but I just tried that and it doesn't work

Comment: Apologies, a bit embarrassing but I wasn't testing this properly, it does work, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, please.

```
$('#listSelector option:first-child').val(response.posts[0].url);
```